# .htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters - Apache error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using this RewriteRule in my .htaccess file I'm getting RewriteRule: Bad flag delimiters which is returning a 500 error in the browser. The .htaccess file is in the root.

Here's the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=l

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and here's the apache error:

```
[Fri May 05 16:11:16.180048 2017] [core:alert] [pid 8924:tid 1708] [client ::1:58526] C:/lol/htdocs/proyecto_cf/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

Comment: That error does not appear to relate to the directive you have posted? Unless you have some hidden characters in that line?

Comment: That's the entire code. and it seems like dont have error.. but i'm getting a 500 error in the browser

Comment: Note that `!=d` should be `!-d`, etc. as explained below (however, that won't result in an error). Just try copying this code back into your `.htaccess` file and if you still get a 500 error then check your error log again.

Comment: I just tried it, now the error is: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: There would seem to be _something else_ going on here? What version of Apache? What is the URL you are requesting? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? It's just that there are no "bad flag delimiters" in the directive you have posted. That error suggests there is a problem with `[QSA,L]`. Try removing the `QSA` flag - that may not be reqd here. The reason for copying the code back from StackOverflow is that the SO editor "cleans" the input. I've tried copying the code and trying it myself (in case there is something we are not seeing), but I get no such error when running this code. (?)

Comment: i tried all it but this code saves me

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen !-l, try to delete that line.

```
# Handles directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Handles files 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# If not a file and not a directory we redirect to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The `-l` tests symbolic links and is valid (if it's required). However, the OP is using `=` which will never match (but won't result in a reported error).